# SAS Create a dataset with two Column Values

Tags: sas

I have got a variable &OldCount in SAS Enterprise Guide and I am trying to create a new dataset called Count1 which has one Column Called VarName and a second column Called ColumnCount. I want to create a row where VarName = "OldCountTotal" and ColumnCount = The value of Oldcount (let's say 56).

How do I do this linking the Column Count value to the macro variable created?

[image]

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would do the following (generating just a single-row dataset):

```
data Count1;
    VarName = 'OldCountTotal';
    ColumnCount = &OldCount.;
    output;
run;
```

I assume your variable is defined earlier in the program, something like this:

```
%let OldCount = 56;
```